# HTC Desire HD with Nokia E52 IMEI

Tags: htc-desire-hd, imei

I recently bought HTC desire HD from E-Bay India.
I'm in India and the guy in E-bay imported UK unlocked Desire HD,
I recently check for the IMEI details and I'm shocked, when I checked, Its showing Nokia E52's details.
May I know why I'm getting Nokia's detail for HTC IMEI ?
Any Ideas ?

And I couldn't able to connect my phone in USB Debugging mode, Is it because of this change in IMEI ?
Some one please help asap.

Regards,
Praveen

Comment: There seem to  be only 2 reasons for this: That information is wrong (or you mistyped the IMEI) or the phone was altered (to hide theft, etc.). USB debugging doesn't relate to the phone parts at all (a tab also offers this and needn't have a radio)

Comment: I didn't type it wrong because I verified many times, Its an unlocked phone, I couldn't able to connect to HTC sync too :(
any idea, is it because of the imei change ?

Comment: Just wanted to point out the possibilities. And yeah, that's possible (HTC sync not working). I'd return it, to be honest.

Comment: You mean I should return it to seller ?

Comment: Probably, yes. How big is the chance you get it working yourself? The IMEI is obviously fake, so you would need to find the necessary hack-tools yourself and flash a new IMEI (e.g. of one of your old phones). Just my thoughts.

Comment: You mean I will get the original HTC's IMEI if I hack ?

Answer (score 2):

Do you still have a link to the ebay listing, is it active? A lot of the phones on ebay are fake/imitation phones. Some even have user interfaces made to look like Android, but are actually running a basic feature phone OS. Tools like HTC Sync and ADB that only work with the real hardware often fail when tried on these devices.

Comment: Right now the ADB is working, It was problem with my computer USB port.
But now my worry is about the imei and HTC Sync :(

Comment: This is the link to Product: http://www.ebay.in/itm/181009891492?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1439.l2649

Comment: Hmm, it does seem to have the right specs and single SIM at least. Fakes are often dual SIM, and driver when you plug them in shows they are using a different, cheaper processor/chipset.

Comment: ya, I tried verifying the Item bar codes and all seems to original and UK based but except the IMEI.